# Modifying Dataframe column value

Tags: pandas

I have my pandas dataframe contain data in the following format:

```
SAC1001.K
KAM10120.B01.W001
CLT004.09C
ASMA104
AJAY101.A.KAS.101
```

I wish to modify the column using string manipulation so, that the result is

```
SAC1001.K
KAM10120.B01
CLT004.09C
ASMA104
AJAY101.A
```

How this can be done? Regex looks to be one way but, not sure of it. Any other elegant way to do it? Please guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [109]: df
Out[109]:
                 col
0          SAC1001.K
1  KAM10120.B01.W001
2         CLT004.09C
3            ASMA104
4  AJAY101.A.KAS.101

In [110]: df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'(\..*?)\..*', r'\1')

In [111]: df
Out[111]:
            col
0     SAC1001.K
1  KAM10120.B01
2    CLT004.09C
3       ASMA104
4     AJAY101.A
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way without regex but maybe with too many str

```
df['col'].str.split('.').str[:2].str.join('.')
```